# Several conditions on group of rows in SELECT

Tags: abap, opensql

I'm working on an ABAP program and I have a filter table ZFILTER (CID, FID, ZFIELD, ZVALUE). The content `ZFIELD` and `ZVALUE` pairs like "country"+"DE", "date"+"Q1.2014". To illustrate this with an example:

```
1, 1, "country", "DE"
1, 2, "country", "SE"
1, 3, "date", "Q1.2014"
```

I need to query that table and find the CIDs of the pairs that correspond to my filter criteria. My filter criteria from front-end:

```
country=DE, date=Q1.2014
```

I now want to find all CIDs where the country is "DE" and date is "Q1.2014" and the expected return value of CID is 1.

I've tried the following query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT CID
 FROM ZFILTER INTO TABLE LT_COMFILT
 WHERE ( ZFIELD = 'country' AND ZVALUE = 'DE'  ) 
               AND 
       ( ZFIELD = 'date' AND ZVALUE = 'Q1.2014' )
```

However, obviously, this gives me no result because of the AND between the statements. I'm guessing I'll have to create some sort of subquery but I'm struggling with this in ABAP as it exceeds my Open SQL expertise.

Is there a better way to go about this task or does anyone have input how to accomplish it (perhaps with a syntactical correct example of subquerying in Open SQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem properly, it is precisely the motivation for the existence of the `for all entries` idiom in ABAP Open SQL:

```
data: ls_filter type zfilter,
      lt_filter type table of zfilter,
      lt_result type table of zfilter.

* Fill filter table
ls_filter-zfield = `country`.
ls_filter-zvalue = `DE`.
append ls_filter to lt_filter.
ls_filter-zfield = `date`.
ls_filter-zvalue = `Q1.2014`.
append ls_filter to lt_filter.

* Get result: Important: Don't execute if lt_filter is initial!
if lt_filter is not initial.
  select * from zfilter into table lt_result
           for all entries in lt_filter
           where zfield = lt_filter-zfield
             and zvalue = lt_filter-zvalue.
endif.
```

Comment: Once I had an experience when I used 'for all entries' with 2 fields like you do and I didn't fetch all the records, all I received from that statement was only 1 record per coincidence.

Comment: nmiranda So you think "for all entries" is broken? This would be a very serious accusation.  Prove it! The only serious caveat with `for all entries` is that you have to ensure that the internal table is non-initial. The  above proposal should work.

Comment: I ended up using a combination of FOR ALL ENTRIES IN and a loop over the filter's key/value pair. FOR ALL ENTRIES IN ensures that I'm only considering those entries (CIDs) that were found in the previous iterations.

Comment: Non-initial is not the only caveat with for all entries.  You also have to make sure you select the entire key in your result set or the system will drop repeated values as duplicates.

Comment: Bryan Cain: True, but this is a 0.001 % case compared to the "using for all entries with initial table" trap

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you what you're after.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CID
FROM ZFILTER INTO TABLE LT_COMFILT
WHERE CID IN (SELECT CID FROM ZFILTER WHERE ZFIELD = 'country' AND ZVALUE = 'DE')
  AND CID IN (SELECT CID FROM ZFILTER WHERE ZFIELD = 'date' AND ZVALUE = 'Q1.2014')
```

Comment: It works but it is a little bit inefficient because it fetches whole subset of 1st CID records despite DISTINCT keyword, the date condition should be took into main WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with such SQL subqueried request

```
SELECT cid, zfield, zvalue AS country
  FROM zfilter
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_filter)
  WHERE cid = ANY ( SELECT cid FROM zfilter WHERE zfield = 'country' AND zvalue = 'DE' )
    AND zfield = 'date' AND zvalue = 'Q1.2014').
```

If it has multiple CIDs with DE country and this date then all of them will be fetched.